# Align gridview evenly when children have different height

Tags: android, gridview

I have this GridView:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
```

that has children with the same height, 99% of the time. No problem and it looks like this.

```
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
```

1% of the time, a child could be taller than its siblings and the result is

```
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
|    |  ----
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
```

As shown, child 1 overlaps with its sibling below it.

This is what want to achieve:

```
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
|    |  ----
 ----
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
 ----   ----
|    | |    |
|    | |    |
 ----   ----
```

As you can see, the two children at the middle adjusted so that child 1 has enough room to draw its view.

Tried different config for my gridview but failed. I am stuck and need help.

Answer (score 0):

kindly refer this url , use `Recylerview` instead of `GridView` in xml.
https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a Staggered GridView: https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html

Comment: thanks but this will not honor the alignment described in my question